# restrict minimum quantity to 10

Tags: javascript, jquery

Working with this javascript, for a cart. I have initial qty set to 10 which is fine. But:-

I want this to be minimum qty that can be ordered, but user could order 11 , 12 ... or 300 etc. So minimum is 10 but any amount over that.

Here is the js:

```
            // Create SelectList                                
            var elmProductSelected = $('select[name="'+resultName+'"]',obj);
            if(elmProductSelected.length <= 0){
               elmProductSelected = $("<select></select>").attr("name",resultName).attr("multiple","multiple").hide();
               refreshCartValues();
            }else{ 
               elmProductSelected.attr("multiple","multiple").hide();
               populateCart(); // pre-populate cart if there are selected items  
            }                 
            obj.append(elmProductSelected);

            // prepare the product list
            populateProducts();

            if(options.selected == '1'){
               showCart();
            }else{
               showProductList();
            }          

            $(btShowProductList).bind("click", function(e){
                showProductList();
                return false;
            }); 
            $(btShowCart).bind("click", function(e){
                showCart();
                return false;
            });

            function showCart(){  
                 $(btShowProductList).removeClass("sel");
                 $(btShowCart).addClass("sel");
                 $(elmPLContainer).hide();
                 $(elmCartContainer).show();
            }
            function showProductList(){ 
                 $(btShowProductList).addClass("sel");
                 $(btShowCart).removeClass("sel");  
                 $(elmCartContainer).hide();
                 $(elmPLContainer).show();
            }

            function addToCart(i,qty){
                 var addProduct = products.eq(i);
                 if(addProduct.length > 0){
                    if($.isFunction(options.onAdd)) {
                      // calling onAdd event; expecting a return value
                      // will start add if returned true and cancel add if returned false
                      if(!options.onAdd.call(this,$(addProduct),qty)){
                        return false;
                      }
                    }
                    var pId = $(addProduct).attr(attrProductId);
                    var pName = $(addProduct).attr(attrProductName);
                    var pPrice = $(addProduct).attr(attrProductPrice);

                    // Check wheater the item is already added
                    var productItem = elmProductSelected.children("option[rel=" + i + "]");
                    if(productItem.length > 0){
                        // Item already added, update the quantity and total
                        var curPValue =  productItem.attr("value");
                        var valueArray = curPValue.split('|');
                        var prdId = valueArray[0];
                        var prdQty = valueArray[1];
                        prdQty = (prdQty-0) +  (qty-0);
                        var newPValue =  prdId + '|' + prdQty;
                        productItem.attr("value",newPValue).attr('selected', true);    
                        var prdTotal = getMoneyFormatted(pPrice * prdQty);
                        // Now go for updating the design
                        var lalQuantity =  $('#lblQuantity'+i).val(prdQty);
                        var lblTotal =  $('#lblTotal'+i).html(prdTotal);
                        // show product quantity updated message
                        showHighlightMessage(messageQuantityUpdated);                                                      
                    }else{
                        // This is a new item so create the list
                        var prodStr = pId + '|' + qty;
                        productItem = $('<option></option>').attr("rel",i).attr("value",prodStr).attr('selected', true).html(pName);
                        elmProductSelected.append(productItem);
                        addCartItemDisplay(addProduct,qty);
                        // show product added message
                        showHighlightMessage(messageItemAdded);                            
                    }
                    // refresh the cart
                    refreshCartValues();
                    // calling onAdded event; not expecting a return value
                    if($.isFunction(options.onAdded)) {
                      options.onAdded.call(this,$(addProduct),qty);
                    }
                 }else{
                    showHighlightMessage(messageProductAddError);
                 }
            }

            function addCartItemDisplay(objProd,Quantity){
                var pId = $(objProd).attr(attrProductId);
                var pIndex = products.index(objProd);
                var pName = $(objProd).attr(attrProductName);
                var pPrice = $(objProd).attr(attrProductPrice);
                var prodImgSrc = $(objProd).attr(attrProductImage);
                var pTotal = (pPrice - 0) * (Quantity - 0);
                pTotal = getMoneyFormatted(pTotal);
                // Now Go for creating the design stuff

                $('.scMessageBar',elmCartList).remove();

                var elmCPTitle1 = $('<div></div>').addClass("scCartItemTitle scCartItemTitle1");                            
                if(prodImgSrc && options.enableImage && prodImgSrc.length>0){
                    var prodImg = $("<img></img>").attr("src",prodImgSrc).addClass("scProductImageSmall");
                    if(prodImg && options.enableImageTooltip){
                        prodImg.bind("mouseenter mousemove",function(){
                            showTooltip($(this));                    
                          return false;
                        });
                        prodImg.bind("mouseleave",function (){
                            tooltip.hide();
                            return true;
                        });
                    }
                    elmCPTitle1.append(prodImg);
                }
                var elmCP = $('<div></div>').attr("id","divCartItem"+pIndex).addClass("scCartItem");

                var pTitle =  pName;
                var phtml = formatTemplate(options.cartItemTemplate, $(objProd));
                var elmCPContent = $('<div></div>').html(phtml).attr("title",pTitle);                        
                elmCPTitle1.append(elmCPContent);                        
                var elmCPTitle2 = $('<label>'+pPrice+'</label>').addClass("scCartItemTitle scCartItemTitle2");
                var inputQty = $('<input type="text" value="'+Quantity+'" />').attr("id","lblQuantity"+pIndex).attr("rel",pIndex).addClass("scTxtQuantity2");                    
                $(inputQty).bind("change", function(e){
                    var newQty = $(this).val();
                    var prodIdx = $(this).attr("rel");
                    newQty = newQty - 0;
                    if(validateNumber(newQty)){
                       updateCartQuantity(prodIdx,newQty);
                    }else{
                      var productItem = elmProductSelected.children("option[rel=" + prodIdx + "]");
                      var pValue = $(productItem).attr("value");
                      var valueArray = pValue.split('|'); 
                      var pQty = valueArray[1];
                      $(this).val(pQty);                                                 
                      showHighlightMessage(messageQuantityErrorUpdate);
                    }
                    return true;
                });

                var elmCPTitle3 = $('<div></div>').append(inputQty).addClass("scCartItemTitle scCartItemTitle3");

                var elmCPTitle4 = $('<label>'+pTotal+'</label>').attr("id","lblTotal"+pIndex).addClass("scCartItemTitle scCartItemTitle4");
                var btRemove = $('<a>'+labelRemove+'</a>').attr("rel",pIndex).attr("href","#").addClass("scRemove").attr("title","Remove from Cart");
                $(btRemove).bind("click", function(e){
                    var idx = $(this).attr("rel");
                    removeFromCart(idx);
                    return false;
                });
                var elmCPTitle5 = $('<div></div>').addClass("scCartItemTitle scCartItemTitle5");
                elmCPTitle5.append(btRemove);

                elmCPTitle1.append(elmCPContent);
                elmCP.append(elmCPTitle1).append(elmCPTitle2).append(elmCPTitle3).append(elmCPTitle4).append(elmCPTitle5);
                elmCartList.append(elmCP);
            }

            function removeFromCart(idx){
                var pObj = products.eq(idx);
                var pName = $(pObj).attr(attrProductName)
                var removeMsg = messageConfirmRemove.replace('_PRODUCTNAME_',pName); // display default
                if(confirm(removeMsg)){
                    if($.isFunction(options.onRemove)) {
                      // calling onRemove event; expecting a return value
                      // will start remove if returned true and cancel remove if returned false
                      if(!options.onRemove.call(this,$(pObj))){
                        return false;
                      }
                    }
                    var productItem = elmProductSelected.children("option[rel=" + idx + "]");
                    var pValue = $(productItem).attr("value");
                    var valueArray = pValue.split('|');
                    var pQty = valueArray[1];
                    productItem.remove();
                    $("#divCartItem"+idx,elmCartList).slideUp("slow",function(){$(this).remove();
                    showHighlightMessage(messageItemRemoved);
                    //Refresh the cart
                    refreshCartValues();});
                    if($.isFunction(options.onRemoved)) {
                      // calling onRemoved event; not expecting a return value
                      options.onRemoved.call(this,$(pObj));
                    }
                }
            }

            function updateCartQuantity(idx,qty){
                var pObj = products.eq(idx);
                var productItem = elmProductSelected.children("option[rel=" + idx + "]");
                var pPrice = $(pObj).attr(attrProductPrice);
                var pValue = $(productItem).attr("value");
                var valueArray = pValue.split('|');
                var prdId = valueArray[0];
                var curQty = valueArray[1];                    
                if($.isFunction(options.onUpdate)) {
                    // calling onUpdate event; expecting a return value
                    // will start Update if returned true and cancel Update if returned false
                    if(!options.onUpdate.call(this,$(pObj),qty)){
                      $('#lblQuantity'+idx).val(curQty);
                      return false;
                    }
                }


                var newPValue =  prdId + '|' + qty;
                $(productItem).attr("value",newPValue).attr('selected', true);    
                var prdTotal = getMoneyFormatted(pPrice * qty);
                    // Now go for updating the design
                var lblTotal =  $('#lblTotal'+idx).html(prdTotal); 
                showHighlightMessage(messageQuantityUpdated);
                //Refresh the cart
                refreshCartValues();
                if($.isFunction(options.onUpdated)){
                    // calling onUpdated event; not expecting a return value
                    options.onUpdated.call(this,$(pObj),qty);
                }                    
            }

            function refreshCartValues(){
                var sTotal = 0;
                var cProductCount = 0;
                var cItemCount = 0;
                elmProductSelected.children("option").each(function(n) {
                    var pIdx = $(this).attr("rel"); 
                    var pObj = products.eq(pIdx);                     
                    var pValue = $(this).attr("value");
                    var valueArray = pValue.split('|');
                    var prdId = valueArray[0];
                    var pQty = valueArray[1];
                    var pPrice =  $(pObj).attr(attrProductPrice);
                    sTotal = sTotal + ((pPrice - 0) * (pQty - 0));
                    cProductCount++;
                    cItemCount = cItemCount + (pQty-0);
                });
                subTotal = sTotal;
                cartProductCount = cProductCount;
                cartItemCount = cItemCount;
                elmBottomSubtotalValue.html(getMoneyFormatted(subTotal));
                cartMenu = labelCartMenuName.replace('_COUNT_',cartProductCount);  
                cartMenuTooltip = labelCartMenuNameTooltip.replace('_PRODUCTCOUNT_',cartProductCount).replace('_ITEMCOUNT_',cartItemCount);
                btShowCart.html(cartMenu).attr("title",cartMenuTooltip);

                if(cProductCount <= 0){
                   showMessage(messageCartEmpty,elmCartList);
                }else{
                   $('.scMessageBar',elmCartList).remove();
                }
            }

            function populateCart(){
               elmProductSelected.children("option").each(function(n) {
                    var curPValue =  $(this).attr("value");
                    var valueArray = curPValue.split('|');
                    var prdId = valueArray[0];
                    var prdQty = valueArray[1];
                    if(!prdQty){
                      prdQty = 1; // if product quantity is not present default to 1
                    }
                    var objProd = jQuery.grep(products, function(n, i){return ($(n).attr(attrProductId) == prdId);});                        
                    var prodIndex = products.index(objProd[0]);
                    var prodName = $(objProd[0]).attr(attrProductName);
                    $(this).attr('selected', true);
                    $(this).attr('rel', prodIndex);
                    $(this).html(prodName);
                    cartItemCount++; 
                    addCartItemDisplay(objProd[0],prdQty);                         
               });
               // Reresh the cart
               refreshCartValues();
            }

            function fillCategory(){
               var catCount = 0;
               var catItem = $('<option></option>').attr("value",'').attr('selected', true).html('All');
               elmCategory.prepend(catItem);                   
               $(products).each(function(i,n){
                    var pCategory = $(this).attr(attrCategoryName);
                    if(pCategory && pCategory.length>0){
                      var objProd = jQuery.grep(elmCategory.children('option'), function(n, i){return ($(n).val() == pCategory);});
                      if(objProd.length<=0){
                        catCount++;
                        var catItem = $('<option></option>').attr("value",pCategory).html(pCategory);
                        elmCategory.append(catItem);
                      }                        
                    }

               });
               if(catCount>0){
                  $(elmCategory).bind("change", function(e){
                    $(txtSearch).val('');
                    populateProducts();
                    return true;
                });                      
               }else{
                  elmCategory.hide();
                  lblCategory.hide();
               }
            }


            function populateProducts(searchString){
               var isSearch = false;
               var productCount = 0;
               var selectedCategory = $(elmCategory).children(":selected").val();
               // validate and prepare search string
               if(searchString){
                  searchString = trim(searchString);
                 if(searchString.length>0){
                     isSearch = true;
                     searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
                 }                      
               }
               // Clear the current items on product list
               elmPLProducts.html('');
               // Lets go for dispalying the products
               $(products).each(function(i,n){
                  var productName = $(this).attr(attrProductName);
                  var productCategory = $(this).attr(attrCategoryName);
                  var isValid = true;
                  var isCategoryValid = true;
                  if(isSearch){
                    if(productName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) == -1) {
                      isValid = false;
                    }else{
                      isValid = true;
                    }
                  }
                  // Category filter
                  if(selectedCategory && selectedCategory.length>0){
                    selectedCategory = selectedCategory.toLowerCase();
                    if(productCategory.toLowerCase().indexOf(selectedCategory) == -1) {
                      isCategoryValid = false;
                    }else{
                      isCategoryValid = true;
                    }
                  }

                  if(isValid && isCategoryValid) {
                      productCount++; 
                      var productPrice = $(this).attr(attrProductPrice); 
                      var prodImgSrc = $(this).attr(attrProductImage);

                      var elmProdDiv1 = $('<div></div>').addClass("scPDiv1");
                      if(prodImgSrc && options.enableImage && prodImgSrc.length>0){
                          var prodImg = $("<img></img>").attr("src",prodImgSrc).addClass("scProductImage");                      
                          if(prodImg && options.enableImageTooltip){
                            prodImg.bind("mouseenter mousemove",function(){
                                showTooltip($(this));                    
                              return false;
                            });
                            prodImg.bind("mouseleave",function (){
                                tooltip.hide();
                                return true;
                            });
                          }
                          elmProdDiv1.append(prodImg);
                      }
                      var elmProdDiv2 = $('<div></div>').addClass("scPDiv2"); // for product name, desc & price
                      var productHtml = formatTemplate(options.productItemTemplate, $(this));
                      elmProdDiv2.html(productHtml);                      

                      var elmProdDiv3 = $('<div></div>').addClass("scPDiv3"); // for button & qty    
                      var btAddToCart = $('<a>'+labelAddToCartButton+'</a>').attr("href","#").attr("rel",i).attr("title",labelAddToCartButton).addClass("scAddToCart");
                      $(btAddToCart).bind("click", function(e){
                          var idx = $(this).attr("rel");
                          var qty = $(this).siblings("input").val();
                          if(validateNumber(qty)){
                             addToCart(idx,qty);
                          }else{
                            $(this).siblings("input").val(1);                                                 
                            showHighlightMessage(messageQuantityErrorAdd);
                          }
                          return false;
                      });
                      var inputQty = $('<input type="text" value="10" />').addClass("scTxtQuantity"); //minimum quantity  
                      var labelQty = $('<label>'+labelQuantityText+':</label>').addClass("scLabelQuantity");                    
                      elmProdDiv3.append(labelQty).append(inputQty).append(btAddToCart);                  

                      var elmProds = $('<div></div>').addClass("scProducts");

                      elmProds.append(elmProdDiv1).append(elmProdDiv2).append(elmProdDiv3);
                      elmPLProducts.append(elmProds);
                  }                                                        
               });

               if(productCount <= 0){
                   showMessage(messageProductEmpty,elmPLProducts);
               }
            }

            // Display message
            function showMessage(msg, elm){
              var elmMessage = $('<div></div>').addClass("scMessageBar").hide();
              elmMessage.html(msg);                  
              if(elm){
                 elm.append(elmMessage);
                 elmMessage.show();
              }
            }

            function showHighlightMessage(msg){
              msgBox2.html(msg);
                    msgBox2.fadeIn("fast", function() {
                        setTimeout(function() { msgBox2.fadeOut("fast"); }, 2000); 
                    }); 
            }

            // Show Image tooltip
            function showTooltip(img) {
                  var height = img.height();
                  var width = img.height();
              var imgOffsetTop = img.offset().top;
              jQuery.log(img.offset());                
              jQuery.log(img.position());
              jQuery.log("--------------");
              tooltip.html('');
              var tImage = $("<img></img>").attr('src',$(img).attr('src')); 
              tImage.height(toolMaxImageHeight);
              tooltip.append(tImage);
                var top = imgOffsetTop - height ;
                var left = width + 10;
              tooltip.css({'top':top, 'left':left});    
              tooltip.show("fast");                                              
            }

            function validateNumber(num){
              var ret = false;
              if(num){
                num = num - 0;
                if(num && num > 0){
                   ret = true;
                }
              }
              return ret;
            }

            // Get the money formatted for display
            function getMoneyFormatted(val){
              return val.toFixed(2);
            }
            // Trims the blankspace
            function trim(s){
                var l=0; var r=s.length -1;
                while(l < s.length && s[l] == ' ')
                {   l++; }
                while(r > l && s[r] == ' ')
                {   r-=1;   }
                return s.substring(l, r+1);
            }
            // format the product template
            function formatTemplate(str, objItem){
              resStr =str.split("<%=");
              var finalStr = '';
              for(i=0;i<resStr.length;i++){
                var tmpStr = resStr[i];
                valRef = tmpStr.substring(0, tmpStr.indexOf("%>")); 
                if(valRef!='' || valRef!=null){
                  var valRep = objItem.attr(valRef); //n[valRef]; 
                  if(valRep == null || valRep == 'undefined'){
                     valRep = '';
                  }
                  tmpStr = tmpStr.replace(valRef+'%>',valRep);
                  finalStr += tmpStr;
                }else{
                  finalStr += tmpStr;
                }
              }
              return finalStr;
            }

    });  
};  

// Default options
$.fn.smartCart.defaults = {
      selected: 0,  // 0 = produts list, 1 = cart   
      resultName: 'products_selected[]', 
      enableImage: false,
      enableImageTooltip: false,
      enableSearch: false,
      enableCategoryFilter: true,
      productItemTemplate:'<strong><%=pname%></strong><br /><small><%=pdesc%></small><br /><strong>Price: $<%=pprice%></strong>',
      cartItemTemplate:'<strong><%=pname%></strong>',
      // Events
      onAdd: null,      // function(pObj,quantity){ return true; }
      onAdded: null,    // function(pObj,quantity){ }
      onRemove: null,   // function(pObj){return true;}
      onRemoved: null,  // function(pObj){ } 
      onUpdate: null,   // function(pObj,quantity){ return true; }
      onUpdated: null,  // function(pObj,quantity){ } 
      onCheckout: null  // function(Obj){ } 
};

jQuery.log = function(message) {
  if(window.console) {
     console.debug(message);
  }
};
```

})(jQuery);

I have qty currently set to 10 on this line :

```
var inputQty = $('<input type="text" value="10" />').addClass("scTxtQuantity"); //minimum quantity
```

ADDED:

```
// Create Bottom bar
            var elmBottomBar = $('<div></div>').addClass("scBottomBar");
            var elmBottomSubtotalText = $('<label>'+labelTotal+':</label>').addClass("scLabelSubtotalText");
            var elmBottomSubtotalValue = $('<label>'+getMoneyFormatted(subTotal)+'</label>').addClass("scLabelSubtotalValue");
            var btCheckout = $('<a>'+labelCheckout+'</a>').attr("href","#").addClass("scCheckoutButton");                
            $(btCheckout).click(function() {
               if($.isFunction(options.onCheckout)) {
                  // calling onCheckout event;
                  options.onCheckout.call(this,elmProductSelected);
               }else{
                  $(this).parents("form").submit();                   
               }
               return false;
            });
            elmBottomBar.append(btCheckout).append(elmBottomSubtotalValue).append(elmBottomSubtotalText);
            obj.append(elmBottomBar);
```

Comment: You are checking the quantity server-side as well aren't you...

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure what problem you are facing while doing this thing...i think this can be easier..try this way..

```
if(inputQty.val()<10){alert("please select at least 10 quantity")}
```

i think so you can put it here, even i am not sure but think so.

```
 $(inputQty).bind("change", function(e){
                var newQty = $(this).val();
                if(newQty<10){alert("please select at least 10 quantity")}
                //rest of your code will go after this of bind function
```

Comment: where would we put that though >?

Comment: or you can put this code in your validateNumber function!!hope this helps:)

Comment: Hmmm Demo here : http://sitehelp.com.au/demos/cart/
If need be can post the php code.

Comment: Updated question with onClick event, what do I need to do ?

Comment: on onclick of that event get the value of that input field and check it whether it is lesser than 10 are not...i didn't get your updated question...and if you want to ask any thing more then please hurry..now i am close to my exit time :)

Comment: Its in the original question at the bottom.